# AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET website which uses Azure AD integration. 
When the site is deployed to test server i got an issue where Login process throws an null Reference Exception. The Login works when i login to server and do login from the same machine.

The code where Exception is thrown :

```
Line 80:      AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
Line 81:      AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode( code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), credential, graphResourceId);                           
Line 82:      AuthenticationHelper.token = result.AccessToken;
Line 83:      return Task.FromResult(0);
```

The Exception is thrown on Line 81.

```
Exception Stack Trace:
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Ektron.WAAD.Startup.<ConfigureAuth>b__3(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context) in d:\Websites\GS1Auth\App_Code\CSCode\WAAD\Startup.auth.cs:81
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +6672
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +7875
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +49
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1008
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +483
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +291
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +1107
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +291
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +293
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +208
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +443
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I am trying to resolve this issue for days now but without success. 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is because HttpContext.Current is null